# Inserting Map records into Cassandra using datastax

Tags: java, cassandra, batch-processing, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax java driver for communicating with cassandra, I have requirement to insert map into cassandra but in the form of each **key,value of map** as individual record. Below is my sample table schema

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    key int PRIMARY KEY,
    value text
)
```

and below is sample code what I am using

```
      String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO test.emp(key,value) values (?,?)";
      PreparedStatement preStmt = session.prepare(insertStatement);      
      BatchStatement batchStmt = new BatchStatement();
          for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
              Integer key = entry.getKey();
              String value = entry.getValue();
              BoundStatement boundStmt = preStmt.bind(key, value);
              batchStmt.add(boundStmt);
            }
          session.executeAsync(batchStmt);
```

above code is working but now I am iterating through the map again (as other application will send map of data, I can't bind params at time of pushing data into map) and binding values to preparedStatement.

Here my requirement is instead of iterating through map again and binding params is there any other simple way like if we send map and prepared statement it will insert data as individual records in to cassandra

Comment: **No, there is no option to bind map into multiple field.**

Comment: @AshrafulIslam ok, Thank you